# Error messages in nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I've three models called `Account`,`User` and `AccountPermission`.

I'm creating the `Account` via `AccountPermission` while creating user.

However, If a problem occurs related with Account :name, the system throws something like that below.

`Account permissions account name has already been taken`

So, I just need to fix this error message.

I've tried to add a message attribute to my validation. It is just appending to actual message.

I've also tried locale thing. Still just appending

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        account:
          attributes:
            name:
              taken: 'bla bla'
```

As far as I see in `ActiveModel`. This message's structure comes from below

locale/en.yml in ActiveModel

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
```

So, Is there any way edit this message painless ? If I even delete the model name, It's enough.

Comment: are you asking can you throw a custom error message when validation fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message is concatenated from the error itself and the attribute name, which is `account_permissions/account.name` in the provided error.

You can add locale for your attribute names like so:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      account: # this is model name
        name: "Name"
```

or

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      account_permissions/account:
        name: "Account name"
```

Comment: Finally ! Thank you so much. `account_permissions/account` works :)

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks @Vasfed. Where did you find this? Where is this documented?

Comment: @Ameen when encountered this on my project - had to read through the rails sources, did not find any documentation